# How many multiple imputation datasets should we make?

Tags: missing-data

Multiple imputation is based on making m different datasets and analyzing them each independently then aggregating over all their information as a whole.

How many imputed datasets should we make?

Answer (score 2):

The rule of thumb used to be that 5 was enough, and you still hear it occasionally. However, over time more and more examples occurred where that proved to be problematic, so now more than 5 is often advised. Sometimes I have heard the number 20, but the real answer is that it depends on the exact problem: How many observations do you have, how many missing values do you want to impute, what is the exact pattern in the missingness, how complicated is the imputation model, how complicated is the substantive model, how complicated are the coefficients you want to interpret from that model, etc, etc. The more complicated the problem, the more imputations you need.

Comment: How do we determine whether m is a good amount?

Comment: That is tough. Most people just hope that $m$ is enough. Others try $2\times m$ and see if the pooled estimates and standard errors change. If not, then $m$ is fine, if it does change then try $3\times m$, etc, till your model is stable. Since there is randomness involved in the imputation process this still requires some good judgement.

Comment: Hm - thanks for the response. But I'd really like some objective way for determining whether m is a good amount. Is there a statistical test that I can employ here?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Statistical tests have their (limited) uses, but this is not one of them.